# C++ typeid of of base class pointer to derived class is returning typeid of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, typeid

I have a base virtual class called [Parameter](https://github.com/dtmoodie/parameters/blob/WIP/include/parameters/Parameter.hpp) which then has several templated derived classes such as [TypedParameter](https://github.com/dtmoodie/parameters/blob/WIP/include/parameters/TypedParameter.hpp).
Now I have a function that takes in a Parameter* which needs to look up the exact type of the pointer.

```
void Serializer::Serialize(cereal::BinaryOutputArchive& ar, Parameter* param)
{
    auto itr = _binary_serializers.find(Loki::TypeInfo(typeid(*param)));
    ar(cereal::make_nvp("type", std::string(typeid(*param).name())));
    if(itr != _binary_serializers.end())
    {
        itr->second.second(ar, param);
    }
}
```

I am calling this from my unit test code with the following:

```
TypedParameter<int> test;
test.UpdateData(5);
{
    std::ofstream ofs("test.xml");
    cereal::XMLOutputArchive ar(ofs);
    Parameters::Cereal::Serializer::instance()->Serialize(ar, &test);
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that the pointer is pointing to the correct derived type and it has all the correct derived type information displayed in the debugger, however typeid(*param).name() always returns "class Parameters::Parameter".

I am using visual studio 2013x64 on windows 7.  Why can't typeid get the correct type information?

To make things easier to understand without parsing my entire project, TypedParameter is a concrete class with the following inheritance:

Parameter -> ITypedParameter< T > -> MetaParameter< T > -> TypedParameter< T >

Comment: It should work. Try to create an [mcve] and post it here.

Comment: What do you mean by "base virtual class"? Does `Parameter` contain virtual function? Or it serves as a virtual base class for `ITypedParameter<T>`?

Comment: Parameter contains virtual functions and ITypedParameter derives from it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce this error with several simplified test cases.  I've tried simulating the lib / executable placement of the base / derived type, and I've tried simulating the inheritance structure.

Comment: I am using gcc 9.3.0 on ubuntu, in my case typeid(DerivedPtr) always return typeinf(Base*). Not sure it is a bug for this particular compiler version or not.  However, dynamic_cast<derived*>(DerivedPtr) works properly and returns not nullptr.